# Black screen after resume from hibernate

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ssd, performance, hibernate

Here's my config:

- Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit)
- i5 + 8GB (1600MHz)
- Samsung 850 Pro (256GB)

My disk is giving me around 540MB/sec read speed, so I get a resume time of about 15-17 seconds which is expected (8GB divided by 500MB/sec).

The problem however is that after the resume has completed and Windows is about to display the login screen, the display instead goes black. It keeps in that state for maybe 70-80 seconds more, after which the login screen appears just normally.

I have ensured that I have the latest display drivers on my machine. This is Dell EliteDesk 800 G1 (SFF), so the HP Drivers Update utility keeps track of the latest drivers etc.

What else could be the problem, or is it a known issue?

Comment: Did this start happening recently? If it's been happening from the beginning and you're sure you have the latest graphics driver installed, try lowering your UAC setting so it doesn't dim the desktop. If that doesn't help remember to reset it back to the way it was.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue, it is normal. In that 10-15 seconds the system is already done filling the memory but it has to restart some scheduling mechanisms (O.S. is up&running but not yet started to schedule high level user apps) and switch to the logon screen. 10 secs is very normal.

Comment: Thanks. I just repeated the process to measure the actual black screen time and it turned out to be a whooping 79 seconds. Don't know why my original impression was of 10 seconds. I have updated my question.